# Meu formulário PHP não conecta com banco de dados

Tags: php, html, sql, banco-de-dados, conexão

Estou desenvolvendo meu primeiro formulário para ser aplicado no trabalho. Porém estou com dificuldades para conecta- lo com meu banco de dados. Creio que não estou utilizando as variáveis corretas.

Minha conexao.php

```php
<?php

$servername = "localhost:8080";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db_name = "auditoria";

// Create connection
$conexao = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db_name);

?>
```

Possuo código inserir_nc.php

```php
<?php

include 'conexao.php';

// variáveis name para inserir no banco de dados    

$sql = " INSERT INTO `auditoria_ofc`(`semana`, `dia`, `linha`, `modelo`, `processo`,`nc`, `detalhenc` , `estacao` , `evidencia`, `contramedida`, `operador` ,  `setor`, `responsavel` , `status`)
        VALUES 
   
        ('" . $_POST['semana'] . "',
        '" . $_POST['dia'] . "',
        '" . $_POST['linha'] . "',
        '" . $_POST['modelo'] . "',
        '" . $_POST['processo'] . "',
        '" . $_POST['nc1'] . "',
        '" . $_POST['detalhenc1'] . "',
        '" . $_POST['estacao1'] . "',
        '" . $_POST['evidencia1'] . "',
        '" . $_POST['contramedida1'] . "',
        '" . $_POST['operador1'] . "',
        '" . $_POST['setor1'] . "',
        '" . $_POST['responsavel1'] . "',
        '" . $_POST['status1'] . "'),
    
   
        ('" . $_POST['semana'] . "',
        '" . $_POST['dia'] . "',
        '" . $_POST['linha'] . "',
        '" . $_POST['modelo'] . "',
        '" . $_POST['processo'] . "',
        '" . $_POST['nc2'] . "',
        '" . $_POST['detalhenc2'] . "',
        '" . $_POST['estacao2'] . "',
        '" . $_POST['evidencia2'] . "',
        '" . $_POST['contramedida2'] . "',
        '" . $_POST['operador2'] . "',
        '" . $_POST['setor2'] . "',
        '" . $_POST['responsavel2'] . "',
        '" . $_POST['status2'] . "'),
    
        
   
        ('" . $_POST['semana'] . "',
        '" . $_POST['dia'] . "',
        '" . $_POST['linha'] . "',
        '" . $_POST['modelo'] . "',
        '" . $_POST['processo'] . "',
        '" . $_POST['nc3'] . "',
        '" . $_POST['detalhenc3'] . "',
        '" . $_POST['estacao3'] . "',
        '" . $_POST['evidencia3'] . "',
        '" . $_POST['contramedida3'] . "',
        '" . $_POST['operador3'] . "',
        '" . $_POST['setor3'] . "',
        '" . $_POST['responsavel3'] . "',
        '" . $_POST['status3'] . "')        
        ";
   
$inserir = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);

?>
```

E meu index.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    

    <!-- CSS only -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style type="text/css">
        #tamanhoContainer {
            width: 500px;
        }
    </style>

</head>


<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Inicio</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs- target="#navbarScroll" aria-controls="navbarScroll" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarScroll">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto my-2 my-lg-0 navbar-nav-scroll" style="--bs-scroll-height: 100px;">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">NC</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            Opções
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Lista de Funcionários</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
                            <li>
                                <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                </ul>
                <form class="d-flex" role="search">
                    <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Procurar" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Procurar</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container" id="tamanhoContainer" style=" margin-top: 40px">
        <h4>Formulário de Auditoria</h4>

        <form action="inserir_nc.php" method="post" style="margin-top:20px">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Semana</label>
                <input type="week" class="form-control" name="semana" placeholder="Insira a semana">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Data</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dia" placeholder="Insira a data">
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Linha</label>
                <select class="form-select" name="linha">
                    <option selected>Selecione a linha</option>
                    <option>Main_01</option>
                    <option>Main_02</option>
                    <option>Main_03</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Modelo</label>
                <select class="form-select" name="modelo">
                    <option selected>Selecione o modelo</option>
                    <option>A135</option>
                    <option>A235</option>
                    <option>A325</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Processo</label>
                <select class="form-select" name="processo">
                    <option selected>Selecione o processo</option>
                    <option>Main</option>
                    <option>Sub</option>
                    <option>Laser Printer</option>
                    <option>3 insp</option>
                    <option>Rework</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label> Não Conformidades</label>
            </div>



            <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
                <div class="accordion-item">
                    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
                        <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                            NC #1
                        </button>
                    </h2>
                    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse " aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                        <div class="accordion-body">
                            <div class=" form-group">
                                <label>NC</label>
                                <select class="form-select" name="nc1">
                                    <option>Selecione a NC</option>
                                    <option>Check_list_1</option>
                                    <option>Check_list_2</option>
                                    <option>Check_list_2</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class=" form-group">
                                <label>Detalhe NC</label>
                                <select class="form-select" name="detalhenc1">
                                    <option>Selecione o detalhe NC</option>
                                    <option>ET desatualizada</option>
                                    <option>Não há ET</option>
                                    <option>Spec div ET</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class=" form-group">
                                <label>Estação</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="estacao1" placeholder="Insira a estação">
                            </div>

                            <div class=" form-group">
                                <label>Evidencia</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="evidencia1" placeholder="Insira a evidencia">
                            </div>

                            <div class=" form-group">
                                <label>Contramedida</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contramedida1" placeholder="Insira a contramedida">
                            </div>

                            <div class=" form-group">
                                <label>Operador</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="operador1" placeholder="Insira a matricula">
                            </div>

                            <div class=" form-group">
                                <label>Setor</label>
                                <select class="form-select" name="setor1">
                                    <option>Selecione o setor</option>
                                    <option>Produção</option>
                                    <option>Manutenção</option>
                                    <option>Inovação</option>
                                    <option>Engenharia</option>
                                    <option>Qualidade</option>
                                    <option>Pro-3M</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class=" form-group">
                                <label>Responsavel</label>
                                <select class="form-select" name="responsavel1">
                                    <option>Selecione o responsável</option>
                                    <option>Adriano Cavalcante</option>
                                    <option>André Maciel</option>
                                    <option>Aiubyo Silva</option>
                                    <option>Casio Azevedo</option>
                                    <option>Charles Muller</option>
                                    <option>Daniela Passos</option>
                                    <option>Deimerson Silva</option>
                                    <option>Elcione Carvalho</option>
                                    <option>Fabiano Assunção</option>
                                    <option>Fran Rossy</option>
                                    <option>Fabio Lima</option>
                                    <option>James Silva</option>
                                    <option>Jandria Souza</option>
                                    <option>Janildy Garcia</option>
                                    <option>Jhene Soares</option>
                                    <option>Karine Aguiar</option>
                                    <option>Ligia Madureira</option>
                                    <option>Marcos Barbosa</option>                                   
                                    <option>Ralcilande Oliveira</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>  

                            <div class=" form-group">
                                <label>Status</label>
                                <select class="form-select" name="status1">
                                    <option>Selecione o status</option>
                                    <option>OK</option>
                                    <option>Pendente</option>
                                    </select>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>




                <div class="accordion-item">
                    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingTwo">
                        <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                            NC #2
                        </button>
                    </h2>
                    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                        <div class="accordion-body">
                        <div class=" form-group">
                                <label>NC</label>
                                <select class="form-select" name="nc2">
                                    <option>Selecione a NC</option>
                                    <option>Check_list_1</option>
                                    <option>Check_list_2</option>
                                    <option>Check_list_3</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class=" form-group">
                                <label>Detalhe NC</label>
                                <select class="form-select" name="detalhenc2">
                                    <option>Selecione o detalhe NC</option>
                                    <option>ET desatualizada</option>
                                    <option>Não há ET</option>
                                    <option>Spec div ET</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class=" form-group">
                                <label>Estação</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="estacao2" placeholder="Insira a estação">
                            </div>

                            <div class=" form-group">
                                <label>Evidencia</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="evidencia2" placeholder="Insira a evidencia">
                            </div>

                            <div class=" form-group">
                                <label>Contramedida</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contramedida2" placeholder="Insira a contramedida">
                            </div>

                            <div class=" form-group">
                                <label>Operador</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="operador2" placeholder="Insira a matricula">
                            </div>

                            <div class=" form-group">
                                <label>Setor</label>
                                <select class="form-select" name="setor2">
                                    <option>Selecione o setor</option>
                                    <option>Produção</option>
                                    <option>Manutenção</option>
                                    <option>Inovação</option>
                                    <option>Engenharia</option>
                                    <option>Qualidade</option>
                                    <option>Pro-3M</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class=" form-group">
                                <label>Responsavel</label>
                                <select class="form-select" name="responsavel2">
                                    <option>Selecione o responsável</option>
                                    <option>Adriano Cavalcante</option>
                                    <option>André Maciel</option>
                                    <option>Aiubyo Silva</option>
                                    <option>Casio Azevedo</option>
                                    <option>Charles Muller</option>
                                    <option>Daniela Passos</option>
                                    <option>Deimerson Silva</option>
                                    <option>Elcione Carvalho</option>
                                    <option>Fabiano Assunção</option>
                                    <option>Fran Rossy</option>
                                    <option>Fabio Lima</option>
                                    <option>James Silva</option>
                                    <option>Jandria Souza</option>
                                    <option>Janildy Garcia</option>
                                    <option>Jhene Soares</option>
                                    <option>Karine Aguiar</option>
                                    <option>Ligia Madureira</option>
                                    <option>Marcos Barbosa</option>                                   
                                    <option>Ralcilande Oliveira</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>  

                            <div class=" form-group">
                                <label>Status</label>
                                <select class="form-select" name="status2">
                                    <option>Selecione o status</option>
                                    <option>OK</option>
                                    <option>Pendente</option>
                                    </select>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>









                <div class="accordion-item">
                    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingThree">
                        <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                            NC #3
                        </button>
                    </h2>
                    <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                        <div class="accordion-body">
                        <div class=" form-group">
                                <label>NC</label>
                                <select class="form-select" name="nc3">
                                    <option>Selecione a NC</option>
                                    <option>Check_list_3</option>
                                    <option>Check_list_2</option>
                                    <option>Check_list_3</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class=" form-group">
                                <label>Detalhe NC</label>
                                <select class="form-select" name="detalhenc3">
                                    <option>Selecione o detalhe NC</option>
                                    <option>ET desatualizada</option>
                                    <option>Não há ET</option>
                                    <option>Spec div ET</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class=" form-group">
                                <label>Estação</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="estacao3" placeholder="Insira a estação">
                            </div>

                            <div class=" form-group">
                                <label>Evidencia</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="evidencia3" placeholder="Insira a evidencia">
                            </div>

                            <div class=" form-group">
                                <label>Contramedida</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contramedida3" placeholder="Insira a contramedida">
                            </div>

                            <div class=" form-group">
                                <label>Operador</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="operador3" placeholder="Insira a matricula">
                            </div>

                            <div class=" form-group">
                                <label>setor</label>
                                <select class="form-select" name="setor3">
                                    <option>Selecione o setor</option>
                                    <option>Produção</option>
                                    <option>Manutenção</option>
                                    <option>Inovação</option>
                                    <option>Engenharia</option>
                                    <option>Qualidade</option>
                                    <option>Pro-3M</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class=" form-group">
                                <label>Responsavel</label>
                                <select class="form-select" name="responsavel3">
                                    <option>Selecione o responsável</option>
                                    <option>Adriano Cavalcante</option>
                                    <option>André Maciel</option>
                                    <option>Aiubyo Silva</option>
                                    <option>Casio Azevedo</option>
                                    <option>Charles Muller</option>
                                    <option>Daniela Passos</option>
                                    <option>Deimerson Silva</option>
                                    <option>Elcione Carvalho</option>
                                    <option>Fabiano Assunção</option>
                                    <option>Fran Rossy</option>
                                    <option>Fabio Lima</option>
                                    <option>James Silva</option>
                                    <option>Jandria Souza</option>
                                    <option>Janildy Garcia</option>
                                    <option>Jhene Soares</option>
                                    <option>Karine Aguiar</option>
                                    <option>Ligia Madureira</option>
                                    <option>Marcos Barbosa</option>                                   
                                    <option>Ralcilande Oliveira</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>  

                            <div class=" form-group">
                                <label>Status</label>
                                <select class="form-select" name="status3">
                                    <option>Selecione o status</option>
                                    <option>OK</option>
                                    <option>Pendente</option>
                                    </select>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>    



    </div>







    <br>
    <div style="text-align:center">
        <input type="submit" id="botao" class="btn btn-primary" value="Finalizar Auditoria">
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>




    <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Este meu formulário após isso, na evidencia, irei colocar para adicionar foto...mas primeiro gostaria de ajudar de como conectar.

Meu banco de dados , segue:

```
INSERT INTO `auditoria_ofc`(`id`, `semana`, `dia`, `linha`, `modelo`, `processo`, `nc`, `detalhenc`, `estacao`, `evidencia`, `contramedida`, `operador`, `setor`, `responsavel`, `status`) VALUES ('[value-1]','[value-2]','[value-3]','[value-4]','[value-5]','[value-6]','[value-7]','[value-8]','[value-9]','[value-10]','[value-11]','[value-12]','[value-13]','[value-14]','[value-15]')
```

Answer (score -2):

Se o código de conexão estiver estiver igual no seu post, a linha da variável $conexão está comentada. Pule uma linha após o comentário para ver se funciona.

```
    // Create connection
    $conexao = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db_name);
```

Caso esse não for o problema, tente usar o **die** para mostrar qual problema ocorreu e posta aqui:

```
<?php

    $servername = "localhost:8080"; $username = "root"; $password = ""; $db_name = "auditoria";

    $conexao = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db_name);

    if ($conexao->connect_error) {
    die("Conexão falhou: " . $conexao->connect_error);
    } else {
    echo "Conectou";
    } 

?>
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).